# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException No properties to serialize found on class com.suman_miazi.e_exam.utils.f

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pojo

This crush is making me crazy. i am using firebase firestore to store user info. my user model class is given below.

```
public class User_data implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private String institute;
    private String subject;
    private String previous_score;
    private String rank;
    private int points;
    private ArrayList enrolled = new ArrayList();
    private String profileImage;
    private String token;

    public User_data(){ }



 public static final Creator<User_data> CREATOR = new Creator<User_data>() {
        @Override
        public User_data createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new User_data(in);
        }

        @Override
        public User_data[] newArray(int size) {
            return new User_data[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(this.name);
        parcel.writeString(this.institute);
        parcel.writeString(this.subject);
        parcel.writeString(this.previous_score);
        parcel.writeString(this.rank);
        parcel.writeInt(this.points);
        parcel.writeList(this.enrolled);
        parcel.writeString(this.profileImage);
    }

    public User_data(Parcel parcel) {
        this.name = parcel.readString();
        this.institute = parcel.readString();
        this.subject = parcel.readString();
        this.previous_score = parcel.readString();
        this.rank = parcel.readString();
        this.points = parcel.readInt();
        this.enrolled = parcel.readArrayList(null);
        this.profileImage = parcel.readString();
    }

// all getter and setter is also implemented here
}
```

also i implemented all getter and setter for all of the member variable.

the problem is I am facing is the ArrayList. what is the right way to read and write ArrayList which will be used to hold firestore array value?

the firebase crashlytics giving me the below crash report.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class com.suman_miazi.e_exam.utils.f
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(CustomClassMapper.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBoolean(CustomClassMapper.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$200(CustomClassMapper.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.castTypedValue(DocumentSnapshot.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.fromDocument(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.castTypedValue(DocumentSnapshot.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.fromDocument(QueryDocumentSnapshot.java)
       at com.suman_miazi.e_exam.firestore_settings.RetrieveDataSnippets.addUserEnrollment(RetrieveDataSnippets.java)
       at com.suman_miazi.e_exam.firestore_settings.-$$Lambda$RetrieveDataSnippets$qj10Mkz-IKZavgwYr8tGqqgO84k.onSuccess(-.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(zzn.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

there is no class name f

```
No properties to serialize found on class com.suman_miazi.e_exam.utils.f
```

all code is working fine in debug mode. but in release app is crashing.

Please anyone give me a solution. I tried so many things but could not solve it

Comment: Try changing your `points` variable to the `Integer` type instead of `int` and make sure your getters and setters are `public`. Let me know if this solved your issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @SumonMiazi Has the comment I provided fixed the issue you were facing?

Comment: @ralemos i also tried using Integer but the problem was not solved. I don't know where did i do wrong. But now i have solved the problem by using setter method to initialize the object from firestore document.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by avoiding the below method to cast and use the public setter function to initialize the object.

**OLD Method:**

```
User_data user_data = documentSnapshot.toObject(User_data.class);
```

**New Method:**

```
user_data.setName(documentSnapshot.getString("name"));    
user_data.setInstitute(documentSnapshot.getString("institute"));
user_data.setSubject(documentSnapshot.getString("subject"));
user_data.setPoints(Objects.requireNonNull(documentSnapshot.getLong("poins")).intValue());
user_data.setToken(documentSnapshot.getString("token"));
user_data.setProfileImage(documentSnapshot.getString("profileImage"));
```